# jar files used for the below imports

Tags: java, httpclient

Anyone used these imports in your files...?

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;
```

I have an example that uses these imports. I have commons-codec-1.6.jar/httpclient-4.1.2.jar/httpcore-4.1.2.jar/commons-logging.jar in my classpath. Still the import fails. any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

That's [Apache commons-httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). And the [Javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/index.html) for that library.